# Can not install vue-mode on Emacs 25

Tags: package, debugging, load

I have emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

I want to install vue-mode package. But I am getting this error message:

```
vue-mode is an incompatible package.                                                                                                                                    

     Status: Incompatible because it depends on uninstallable packages.                                                                                                 
    Archive: melpa                                                                                                                                                      

    Version: 20190415.231                                                                                                                                               
    Summary: Major mode for vue component based on mmm-mode                                                                                                             
   Requires: mmm-mode-0.5.5 (not available), vue-html-mode-0.2, ssass-mode-0.2, edit-indirect-0.1.4                                                                     
   Keywords: [languages]
```

Screenshot:

[image]

But when I type <kbd>M</kbd> + x + `package-refresh-contents`, I do not see the packages complained about: **vue-html-mode-0.2**, **ssass-mode-0.2** and **edit-indirect-0.1.4**.

How to fix this ?

Comment: A guess is that library `mmm-mode-0.5.5`, listed as `not available` in `Requires:`, needs to be made available (e.g. installed as package or present in your `load-path`.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to install those packages separately but they are not listed when I type `package-refresh-contents`

Comment: Can you add to your question the value of the variable `package-archives`?

Comment: As @matteol suggested, please add the current value of the variable `package-archive` in the description of the question. Just `C-h` `v` `package-archives`.